# How to run a function everytime a div changes its size?

Tags: javascript, events, resize

How to run a function everytime a div changes its size?

Div's size normally changes when the window changes its size, but NOT only;
The new width/height are not everytime set by css, but I need to get the real width/height of that height when everytime it changes.

I use jQuery, so based on this would be good;

It must work in chrome, ff2, ff3, ie6(if can't work I might lag user's browser with a timer xD) ie7, safari, opera... in other words the most popular browsers

thanks ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-resize-plugin/) is a plugin that extends jQuery's `resize()` event to work on any element, not just the window.

Comment: Please do not use this jQuery plugin. It's really slow and not accurate at all. Please see my answer below for a better solution.

Answer (score 4):

This question has been asked '11, but as I came here via Google I want to clarify some things.

1) There is already a solid method to check if a element has been changed in almost all browsers. Check for this my lib:

http://marcj.github.io/css-element-queries/

This library has a class `ResizeSensor` which can be used for resize detection. It uses a event-based approach, so it's damn fast and doesn't waste CPU time.

2) Please do **not use** the jQuery onresize plugin as it uses `setTimeout()` loop to check for changes. THIS IS INCREDIBLY SLOW AND NOT ACCURATE.

Answer (score 1):

Try the `onresize` event (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onresize.asp):

```
<div onresize="alert('You have changed the size of the window')"></div>
```

Comment: at first look, w3c seems to grant it only to `window` and `body`

Answer (score 1):

**[Here is a demo that uses polling to accomplish what you need...](http://jsfiddle.net/mdeq7/)**

...but the `resize()` plugin mentioned above looks like better practice if it works the way you need it to.